# Set value to listview when click dialog alert button (multiple onclick listeners)

Tags: android, listview, text, dialog, onclicklistener

```
  listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, int position, long id) {

                TextView accno = view.findViewById(R.id.col_one_four_layout);
                final TextView stage = view.findViewById(R.id.col_four_four_layout);
                final TextView remark = view.findViewById(R.id.col_three_four_layout);
                final String stage_string = stage.getText().toString();

                if (stage_string.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(Audit_offline.this);
                    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.audit_offline_custom);
                    final EditText remarkTv = dialog.findViewById(R.id.remark_dialog);
                    final TextView accTv = dialog.findViewById(R.id.accountno);
                    accTv.setText("Account Number  :   " + accno.getText().toString());


                    Button btn = dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnTempSave_dialog);


                    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            **stage.setText(remarkTv.getText().toString());**
                        }
                    });

                    dialog.show();
                }
```

I want to set the value to " stage.setText(remarkTv.getText().toString());" when alert dialog button click event.  But it's doesn't work.

Comment: I think you're using a wrong approach. You should take a look at notifyDataSetChanged adapter's method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use base adapter and using ViewHolder to try to retrieve values. It's work for me.  `   if ((viewHolder.txt_job_status.getText().toString()).equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {

```
                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mContext);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.audit_offline_custom);
                dialog.setTitle("Update Remark");

                final EditText remarkTv = dialog.findViewById(R.id.remark_dialog);


                final TextView accTv = dialog.findViewById(R.id.accountno);
                accTv.setText("Account Number  :   " + viewHolder.txt_acc_number.getText().toString());
                final String remark = remarkTv.getText().toString();

                Button btn = dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnTempSave_dialog);

                btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
```

//                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), viewHolder.txt_acc_number.getText().toString() + "--" + remarkTv.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            if (remarkTv.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                                new Audit_dialog().showAlertDialog("Information Message", "Remark can't be empty", mContext);
                            } else {
                                db.updateRemark(viewHolder.txt_acc_number.getText().toString(), remarkTv.getText().toString());
                                db.updateStage(viewHolder.txt_acc_number.getText().toString(), "2");
                                dataModel.setJob_status("2");
                                dataModel.setRemark(remarkTv.getText().toString());
                            }

```
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });


                dialog.show();
            }`
```